# Access a MDB file via HTTP using PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

I am attempting to access a `*.mdb` from another server via HTTP and PHP I was able to connect to the file but using the `realpath()` method but the data is served via node.js express and can be accessed via web browser, my code is below

```
$connstr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=`http://server:7000/public/05/201805.mdb`;";
$db_conn->open($connstr);
$rS = $db_conn->execute("SELECT TOP 100 * FROM PCBRESULT ORDER BY DATE DESC");
```

Is this possible or there's another way to do this? any suggestions would be good.

Comment: Access is NOT a server. Connecting to an offsite Access database is a major no-no. You should either have it locally available or available on an SMB share (while you _could_ use an offsite share, I strongly recommend you don't). If you have Node available on the server that has local access to the file, let Node do the querying and output the result as JSON. Then you can work with that JSON in PHP.

Comment: OFF: Why are you using Access, when you have a server with PHP & MySQL?